# How to serialize SortedDictionaty which having a custom IComparer

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

The goal is simple. Make the dictionary serialization order by key DESC.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    var dic = new SortedDictionary<int, string>(new DescComparer<int>())
        {{1, "A"}, {3, "C"}, {4, "D"}, {2, "B"}};
    return Ok(dic);
}

class DescComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly IComparer<T> _defaultComparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    public int Compare([AllowNull] T x, [AllowNull] T y)
    {
        return _defaultComparer.Compare(y, x);
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
{
    "1":"A",
    "2":"B",
    "3":"C",
    "4":"D"
}
```

What I want is:

```
{
    "4":"D",
    "3":"C",
    "2":"B",
    "1":"A"
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The serialized order should not matter. The data structure itself is sorted, so when deserialized, it will be in order again. If you care about the order, you need to serialize using an object that preserves its internal order when serializing.

Comment: Are you using `Newtonsoft.Json` or `System.Text.Json`

Comment: What does `return Ok(dic.Reverse());` return?

Comment: @mjwills -- it works, but returns an array, not a dictionary

Comment: @mjwills -- `Ok(dic.Reverse().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value));` that does it though

Comment: @Andy using `ToDictionary` like that isn't reliable since it is relying on the data coming out of the dictionary in the same order it was inserted (which it currently does, but it explicitly **does not guarantee** that, so it could change in future).

Comment: @Andy I am using ```Newtonsoft.Json```.

Comment: @PeterDuniho My coworker asked me if I could order by the keys in dictionary desc when returing from my API. Since this doesn't matter, I will tell him to do it himself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class DescComparer<T> : IComparer<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    //private readonly IComparer<T> _defaultComparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return y.CompareTo(x);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: The function of your code seems the same like mine...I'm using ```Newtonsoft.Json``` and it returns [1,2,3,4], not [4,3,2,1].

Comment: I'm using Newtonsoft.Json too.Did you mind sharing your Startup.cs?

Comment: Only one line in ```public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)``` is about ```Newtonsoft.Json``` : ```services.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>{options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();})```.